# Attaching USB device

Tags: virtualization, scripting, usb

Just wondering if anybody knows is there any script for vmware to attach or detach USB device?

Comment: I have often wondered the same thing about ESX/Vsphere.  Good Question.

Comment: Which VMware product are you referring to? Workstation, Fusion, Server, ESX, vSphere...

Comment: Any of it. It will be great to find such script for any product.

Comment: But it is workstation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything in the VIX API reference about USB:
[VIX API Reference](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix18_reference/)

So my guess is that with the VIX api alone the answer is no you cannot do this.

This product [powerwf](http://www.powerwf.com/) says:

> PowerWF Studio for VMware is a suite of tools for automating and administering virtual machine operations and the guests within virtual machines. Leveraging the VMware's VIX API plus several other PowerWF activities packs, PowerWF Studio for VMware offers levels of automation typically only seen in enterprise class solutions. The product supports management of VMware Server, Workstation, Player, and Virtual Infrastructure (both ESX and vCenter).

There might be such a capability in their "activity packs". I've never used it so that's just a guess but it looks like they have a free download so might be worth a look.